# Create a constantly enlarging file on Mac OS using terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, storage

I want to free up some storage and clear my System Data on my Mac.

I plan to create a file constantly increasing in size (to force the OS to declare low storage and forcing running apps and the system to begin purging data). After that, I will delete my file and have free space.

How do I create a constantly increasing in size file on my Mac using Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

You need to explain what limit you are looking for.  Creating a "constantly increasing in size" file will eventually eat all your disk space, and the OS will crash, forcing you into recovery.  The standard *nix/osx tool for this is [dd](https://ss64.com/osx/dd.html).

Here's a typical example

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=FileName bs=2048 count=1000
```

The parameters here that are important:

- if=/dev/zero reads from a system file that just has zeros. You will use this exactly as is
- bs=2048 this is the blocksize of the file in bytes (2k).  Use this
- count=1000 Your file will be bs*count, so in this case, 1000k ie. 2mb.
- of=Filename Is the name of the output file.  If you omit this, the data will be written to standard out, which you can use to your advantage by appending the data to an existing file.

Here is a bash script that will slowly create a large file in the /tmp directory.  It adds 2mb to the file each time, then checks free file space, and will run until you hit the threshold, or you can end it in the terminal manually.

The variables involved can be easily modified if you want the iterations to run faster, or make each addition to the file larger.

```
#!/bin/bash
#make_empty_file.sh
echo "Writing to /tmp/empty_file.bin"
touch /tmp/empty_file.bin

let gb="1024*1000*5"
df=`df -Pk . | sed 1d | grep -v used | awk '{ print $4 "\t" }'`

while [ $gb -lt $df ] 
do
    dd if=/dev/zero bs=2048 count=1000 >> /tmp/empty_file.bin
    sleep 2
    df=`df -Pk . | sed 1d | grep -v used | awk '{ print $4 "\t" }'`
    free=$((df/1024))
    echo "$free Megabytes free..."  
done
```

Comment: You need to know how to make your script executable with chmod.

Comment: Threshold is set to 5gb.  So it will run until you have < 5gb of space left.  Change the `let gb="1024*1000*5"` line, and set it to something more or less than 5 in that calculation if you want to take up more space or less.  When you get less than 1g of free space things will really start to bog down, and the os may crash if you are low on memory and swapping.

Comment: Filling the HD won't crash and force you into recovery. This isn't 1998. :)

Comment: @TyR if the machine crashes, when it reboots it will run fsck on the drive.   This is what I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you want to create the file sounds odd to me, but anyways, this is a simple way to create a fast-growing file:

```sh
yes > /path/to/file.txt
```

Comment: how large will this file be?

Comment: The upper limit is 8e9 GB on the older HFS+ with a max of 2^32-1 per Volume, 9e9 GB if you are using Apple File System, on which you can write up to 2^63 of them per Volume.

Comment: It does seem odd, but it's a practical technique these days, sadly. New versions of macOS store lots of purgeable files on your disk, and only delete them when there's pressure on free space.